# Facebook like button doesn't work on localhost

Tags: facebook

Facebook like button doesn't work on localhost . How  can I test the functionality of facebook like button on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), it explains how to use the Like button.